# TypeError when calling dict.keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have some code, in Python which (if it would work) should replace data in a string using a dictionary to do the replacement. eg. key would be the thing that gets replaced, and value would be the replaced data.
Code

```
def replace(data=str, options=dict):
    for i in range(options.keys()):
        data = data.replace(options.keys()[i], options.get(options.keys()[i]))
    return data
```

However, when I call this function, it gives me this error, I have looked online and have found no way of fixing it.
for i in range(options.keys()):
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
How I call this function:

```
test = {
"a":"b",
"c":"d"
}
replace("abcd", test)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace(data=str, options=dict):
    for k, v in options.items():
        data = data.replace(k, v)
    return data
```

Comment: I'd recommend removing `=str` and `=dict` in the function signature however, as now it means that the default value are *the* respective types, and not that the parameter values should be *of* the respective types (which I guess is what you intended to do).